# How do I insert a div from custom function into my HTML code

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am currently working on a project which includes inserting charts based on user input. So, I made an empty div and gave it an id.

```
<div id="chart-area">
    Your Chart will appear here
    <Frappe />
</div>
```

Now when I tried inserting the chart with `appendChild` it gave me `TypeError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'`. Even though my function is returning a `<div>`. This is the code for function that returns the chart. It is stored in a seperate file.

```
import React, { useRef } from "react";
import ReactFrappeChart from "react-frappe-charts";

export default function Frappe(props) {
  const chartRef = useRef();

  const exportChart = () => {
    if (chartRef && chartRef.current) {
      chartRef.current.export();
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <ReactFrappeChart
        ref={chartRef}
        type={"line"}
        colors={"#111"}
        axisOptions={{ xAxisMode: "tick", yAxisMode: "tick", xIsSeries: 1 }}
        height={250}
        data={{
          labels: ["Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat", "Sun"],
          datasets: [{ values: [18, 40, 30, 35, 8, 52, 17, 4] }],
        }}
      />
      <button onClick={exportChart} type="button">
        Export
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

The function that I used for inserting chart is:

```
const plotChart = () => {
  chartArea.appendChild(<Frappe/>)
};
```

I have also tried doing the same with `innerHTML` property and `append`. How can i insert the div returned by `Frappe()` inside div with id `chart-area`

Comment: Thats not really how you should be doing things in an SPA. You should include your `<Frappe/>` component on the page, and then when the user interacts with it, it should get updated and show the chart. There should be no need to append the component.

Comment: Directly interacting with the DOM is almost always the wrong approach in React.  Instead, consider using a state value to determine whether to conditionally show or hide (include or exclude, etc.) the `<Frappe/>` component in your JSX.  Then the `plotChart` operation would simply update that state value.

Comment: try following and check if its works or not `import { render } from 'react-dom';
const plotChart = () => {
 const chartArea = document.getElementById('chart-area'));
 render(<Frappe/>, chartArea);
};`

Comment: @sandeep bro, it's giving the same error

Comment: trying with your approach @david thank you

Comment: seems like you have to first get component html `import { render } from 'react-dom'; 
import ReactDOMServer from "react-dom/server;
const plotChart = () => {  
 const chartArea = document.getElementById('chart-area'));  
 const html = ReactDOMServer.renderToString(
    <Frappe/>
 );
 render(html, chartArea); 
};`

Comment: @Sandeep Even this solution is not working. Thanks though

Answer (score -1):

What I suggest using is the `Element.insertAdjacentHTML` function. So if you have a container element and you would like to insert some HTML inside using javascript then you can simply do something like this:

```
const parentElement = document.querySelector('#parent');

const html = `
    <div id="chart-area">
        Your Chart will appear here
        <Frappe />
    </div>
`;

parentElement.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', html); // here for the first argument just use 'beforeend' for inserting after the last child or 'afterbegin' for inserting before the first child
```

I really hope this helps and you continue using `Element.insertAdjacentHTML` after this project as it is really useful, and let me know if you're still having trouble after this.